# Unable to expand navigation of wordpress website when the browser size is reduced

Tags: php, css, wordpress, hyperlink, wordpress-theming

I am looking for help in [verefly.com](http://verefly.com). I have developed this website with an online theme and have made the necessary changes .My issue is that the navigation menu when the browser is reduced from its original size , does not expand . It should ideally do that and was performing normally until some days ago .

The normal website looks like this :

[image]

The website looks different when the browser is reduced in size :

[image]

In the above picture you will see the navigation menu , however the Plus sign is no longer clickable . Neither does it expand . I am not able to understand where i can change it to work again .

I would appreciate any help .*

*** I tried to check if the secondary Menu had an issue , but nothing is evident ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm.. i see. Try to remove or turn off the script like below. May resolve the problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jwplayer("mediaplayer_vid_5").setup({
       "autostart" : "true",
        "controlbar" : "bottom",
        "file" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGoCeTMgLE0&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
        "flashplayer" : "http://verefly.com/wp-content/plugins/cool-video-gallery/cvg-player/player.swf", "volume" : "70","width" : "640",
                            "height" : "480",
                            "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/pGoCeTMgLE0/0.jpg",
                            "mute" : "false",
                            "stretching" : "fill",
                            "skin" : "http://verefly.com/wp-content/plugins/cool-video-gallery/cvg-player/skins/glow-skin/glow.xml"
                        });
                    });
```

**NEW UPDATE :**
This script is in the article "**Vault in the Ville!**", Let you check in the post in your wordpress admin, there you may inadvertently insert this javascript code. If you find this code, remove it.

Please use browser view source in this url http://verefly.com/2012/06/06/vault-in-the-ville-2/ to see the javascript code what i mean.

Comment: So you want me to remove this segment of code form the website ... what exactly do you think could be the issue

Comment: Yup. But try to just turn off that scripts using /* ... */ and try your navigation menu again.

Comment: I am unable to find it , and change it ... where do you think it would be ??

Comment: @njack : Okay jack, here i clear your problem. The script is in the article "Vault in the Ville!", Let you check in the post in your wordpress admin, there you may inadvertently insert the javascript code.

Comment: I tried this and really did not work , i tried doing this in the mozilla browser aswell and it does not really make any change . the browser shos the erorr but does not resolve

Comment: @njack: now I see your website is back to normal, was able to expand the navigation menu. :)

Comment: Hi fredy , The issue is even after the navigation works it does not work on the current home page it does not work on the remaining pages .. what could be the reason ... should it not be uniform

Comment: Check my answer for what's causing the navigation to get bugged on other pages then home.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're seeing is due to `$(document).ready` never being fired, so (essentially) none of the code in your `custom.js` file is being executed.

As pointed out already, this is because the `jwplayer` instantiation in the middle of your page (on line 399) is failing. `jwplayer` is expecting you to pass in the ID of a container element, but no element with an ID of `mediaplayer_vid_5` exists on the page.

So, you need to either remove this script entirely, or make sure that you are passing in an ID that is actually being used somewhere on the page. Once you've done one of the two, it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the css of your div with id wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 99.9%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: but the div contains other spans and stuff to , dont you think those will get affacted

Comment: have a try.. i tried it by changing it live on your site.. and for me it worked fine.. the div's doesn't fall below sidebar by using this patch..

Comment: I tried changing it but it made no effect : i have my code on the following link : http://pastie.org/7697071 . could you point out . the changes that I have bought till now make the navigation bar open on the first page but not on the remaining pages . on other pages it still not opening

Answer (score 1):

Looks like at the time of my post you have a new problem, you're missing code from the bottom of the source. Check the code after `</div> <!-- #main-content -->` on this page http://verefly.com/video/ (or any other) and compare it to the homepage http://verefly.com/ (you're missing scripts like custom.js + others and you didn't close tags like html, body etc.)

Most probably you didn't include the footer in the PHP code of the theme on the layouts that are used on pages different then the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Write down a media query for the wrapper class for the slandered sizes of the browser sizes. if possible you can do it to the images as well.

Hope it helps